# Eclipse fails to start

Tags: java, eclipse

When I try to start Eclipse Juno on Windows 7 a messagebox saying "An error occured. See the log file" appears and eclipse won't start. I tried either renaming my workspace folder or change eclipse workspace settings stored in eclipse_root_folder\configuration.settings\org.eclipse.core.net.prefs but it doesn't work. I have been using this for 2 months and this didn't happen before. Any solution?

```
!SESSION 2013-03-11 15:17:16.709 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800
java.version=1.6.0_25
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-03-11 15:17:20.919
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: sun.misc.ProxyGenerator$ConstantPool.seTReadOnly()V
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateClassFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.ProxyGenerator.generateProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.annotationForMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.initAnnotationsIfNecessary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationType.getInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations2(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationParser.parseAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.declaredAnnotations(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.isAnnotationPresent(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processFields(InjectorImpl.java:617)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processClass(InjectorImpl.java:575)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processClass(InjectorImpl.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processClassHierarchy(InjectorImpl.java:556)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:319)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:161)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.services.translation.TranslationProviderFactory.bundleTranslationService(TranslationProviderFactory.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultHeadlessContext(E4Application.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createDefaultContext(E4Application.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:557)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:543)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

- I have the latest version of java
- /eclipsepath/eclipse.exe -clean [this isn't working]
- I haven't made any changes on my pc

Comment: Did you upgrade or change your JDK before this started occurring?

Comment: No, it was working 10 minutes ago. Everything is exactly the same on my pc. Nothing changed.

Comment: No, you *don't* have the latest version of Java. The latest would be a 1.7 version.

Comment: @James - You may be seeing the same error message, but your problem could be different. Can you paste the error log from eclipse ?

Comment: What did you do just before the crash?

Comment: I'm sorry but although the software is for programming this is not a programing problem, this is a application problem.

Comment: @MartinBarker Questions about software that is primarily used for programming are on-topic. That means users can ask questions about any problem they're having with an IDE like Eclipse or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Eclipse stores a copy of your project in it's cache. It can happen when Eclipse crashes (that happens) that this cache is corrupted and thus Eclipse won't start again. Starting with '--clean' somethimes fixes this but not always.

In my experience one solution is to delete the project's cache. Look for the '.metadata' folder in your workspace and delete it while Eclipse is NOT running (make a backup just in case). Then launch Eclipse again.

You may loose your Run Configurations preferences which you can then restore from your backup copy of ".metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.debug.core/.launches".

Comment: I run a much less stable version of eclipse, the port to FreeBSD.  Frequently eclipse will crash and subsequently corrupt the project cache files.  When it does, this is the only way that consistently resolves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try to execute following line in command prompt:

```
/eclipsepath/eclipse.exe -clean
```

Answer (score 3):

When even "clean" command fails, I have had good results with

```
eclipse -clean -cleanPersistedState
```

Apart from that, I'd use FileMon by SysInternals (or ProcMon, or similar utility) to try and see what operation exactly is failing, or where is Eclipse looking for its data.

Answer (score 2):

> eclipse.buildId=M20120914-1800 **java.version=1.6.0_25** java.vendor=Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64,
>   WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product
>   org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product Command-line arguments:  **-os win32
>   -ws win32 -arch x86_64** -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

No you don't have latest version of java, your eclipse is using java 1.6, Latest java is 1.8

There seems to be some mismatch ie. OS is win32 and arch is x86_64. Make sure that if OS is 32 bit, Java and Eclipse is also 32 bit

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you downloaded the Eclipse/ JAVA version for the right processor architecture?
Looks like try to run a mixture of 32-bit and 64-bit applications on your system, maybe you updated your eclipse/ java/ etc. or added some new library?

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not using the version of Java that you think you are. You need to specify to Eclipse what JVM to use, via [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini). Otherwise it can pick up unintended versions from your system path.

Answer (score 1):

in your files manager do the following thing.

rm YOUR_WORKSPACE/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap

rm /home/anoop/workspace2/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap

Answer (score 1):

Run the following command in terminal

```
/full/path/to/second/eclipse -clean
```

Answer (score 1):

--clean helped me when i restart after the eclipse crashed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a restore of your computer to yesterday? It's certainly not as elegant as some of these other answers, but I bet *something* changed that you're just not thinking about (or noticing - background update, perhaps?), and a restore will fix whatever that was.